# How to get the List of Port names?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, usb

Is there any way I can get the friend name of a COM Port? Friend name means the user friendly name of the COM Port like "Huwawei 3G Dongle". I am getting the list of COM Ports as displayed here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

try the link it might solve your problem....

http://dariosantarelli.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/c-how-to-programmatically-find-a-com-port-by-friendly-name/